# f is constant on G

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Let $f$ be analytic function of complex variable that assumes only purely imaginary values in a region $G$. Prove that $f$ is constant on $G$.
I am stuck here. Will anybody please help?

Comment: How about using the CR equations?

Comment: Hint : open mapping theorem.

Comment: Will u please elaborate?

Comment: I got it thanks

Comment: But I did not get see-woo's point.pls help

Answer (score 1):

Choose any small disk $D\subseteq G$. If $f$ is constant on $D$, identity theorem implies $f$ is constant on $G$. Otherwise, by the open mapping theorem, $f(D)$ should be open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. 
However, it is impossible since $f(D)$ is contained in $i\mathbb{R}$. (Any open neighborhood of any point in $f(D)$ should contain other points in $\mathbb{C}\backslash i\mathbb{R}$.)